# What's a degree "by resolution"?

Tags: united-kingdom

The screenshot beneath is from [Prof. James Goudkamp's profile](https://7kbw.co.uk/barrister/james-goudkamp/). See the red arrow.

> [image]

1. What's meant "by resolution"?
2. Why was this MA obtained after all his other degrees?

I know that [the Oxbridge MA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Arts_(Oxbridge_and_Dublin)) "is an academic rank, and not a postgraduate qualification", as

> Bachelors of Arts with Honours of these universities are promoted to the title of **Master of Arts** or **Master in Arts (MA)** on application after six or seven years' seniority as members of the university (including years as an undergraduate).

Comment: Not an answer, but in Oxford MAs take academic precedence of Doctors who do not have an MA.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, it's a "free masters degree" to members who otherwise don't qualify for the masters degree, for various reasons.

Here it is, direct from Oxford:

> Conferment of Degrees
>   7.1. The procedures for the conferment, both at the Encaenia and on other occasions, of Degrees by Diploma, Honorary Degrees, Ordinary
>   Degrees, and Degrees by Incorporation shall be determined by
>   regulation, and the regulations concerned shall be published from time
>   to time in a Handbook for the Conduct of University Ceremonies.
>
> 7.2. (1) In the case of a person in any of the categories set out in paragraph (2) below who does not hold, and is not qualified for, any
>   of the Degrees (other than Honorary Degrees) of Doctor of Divinity,
>   Doctor of Civil Law, Doctor of Medicine, Master of Arts, Master of
>   Biochemistry, Master of Chemistry, Master of Earth Sciences, Master of
>   Engineering, Master of Mathematics, or Master of Physics of the
>   University, Council shall as soon as possible propose to Congregation
>   that a Degree of Master of Arts by Resolution be conferred upon that
>   person without fee, if (and only if) he or she holds both a bachelor’s
>   and a doctor’s degree (other than an honorary degree) of any
>   university or universities or of any such other institution or
>   institutions as Council may determine by regulation from time to time,
>   or that at least twenty terms have lapsed since he or she first became
>   a member of a university or such other institution, or, in the case of
>   a person who is not a member of any university, that he or she is at
>   least 25 years of age.
>
> (2) The categories referred to in paragraph (1) above are:
>
> (a) the Chancellor;
>
> (b) the High Steward;
>
> (c) the Vice-Chancellor;
>
> (d) the Proctors;
>
> (e) the heads of all the colleges, societies, and Permanent Private
>   Halls included in Statute V;
>
> (f) the members of the governing bodies of all the colleges and
>   societies included in Statute V (but not of the Permanent Private
>   Halls);
>
> (g) the principal bursar or treasurer of each of the colleges and
>   societies included in Statute V (but not of the Permanent Private
>   Halls), if he or she is not a member of its governing body.
>
> (3) In the case of a person excluded because none of the conditions in
>   paragraphs (1) and (2) above is met, Council shall proceed as soon as
>   possible after one of them has been met.
>
> (4) Nothing in this regulation shall restrict the power of Council to
>   propose to Congregation that a Degree by Resolution be conferred
>   without fee upon any person it considers appropriate.
>
> 7.3. A Degree by Resolution shall be deemed to have been conferred with effect from the approval of the resolution by Congregation.

Comment: The quoted regulations quite specifically apply to a relatively small number of extremely senior posts, and there's no evidence that the person in question held any of those posts. The relevant regulations would be those for the conferring of the MA on an Oxford PhD holder 21 terms after matriculation.

Comment: None of 2(a) to 2(g) mentions "mere" professors. I should perhaps have emphasised *extremely* in my first comment.

Comment: Feel free to expand your answer by explaining which of those categories applies.

Comment: Clause 2(f) covers almost everyone who holds a potentially permanent faculty post in the University. Been there, done that: "this will involve you in no expense, and you need not attend the ceremony" as the letter said.

Answer (score 0):

It's ecactly as described in the wikipedia-article you were linking: He had to spend 6-7 years at Oxford to recieve the title. Since he was faster than this time span with his doctorate, he recieved the Master by Resolution after his Doctor.

The degree "Master of Arts by Resolution" indicates, that no further studies or exams were necessary, but is is given "by resolution".

Comment: This is just not true. Such a degree can be (and is) given within weeks of taking up a post.